# Java Split String on "^^^"

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I was hoping someone could help me with a pattern to split a string strictly on a character sequence of of three `^`, i.e, `^^^`

```
Input: Sample-1^^^Sample-2
Output: String 1: Sample-1 and String-2: Sample-2
```

I tried `\\^\\^\\^` and it works fine for the happy path. But if I give it a string like:

```
Input: Sample-1^^^^Sample-2
```

I get the output as:

```
String 1: Sample-1
String-2: ^Sample-2
```

I tried the pattern `(\\^\\^\\^)` as well, but no luck.

Comment: I'm confused. You want to split it *stricly* one three `^^^`. Unless there's four? Then split it on four?

Comment: It very much depends how your **overall** regex looks like. Please give a true [mcve]. Example code, and example input, and output.

Answer (score 5):

In this case you need `\^+` ([`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/NBczbQ/1)) which match `one or more` literal `^` character :

```
String[] output = input.split("\\^+");
```

Or if you want to match only `3 or 4` of literal `^` character you can use :

```
String[] output = input.split("\\^{3,4}");
```

Or if you want to match `3 or more` of literal `^` character you can use :

```
String[] output = input.split("\\^{3,}");
```